# Vim auto indent large array litterals

Tags: vim, indentation, code-formatting, vim-plugin, auto-indent

I'm faced with the problem of ugly-looking lists on several lines for which the lines do not have the same length.

Here take this example:

```
    voxels = [[90, 90,    90],
              [110, 110, 110],
              [40, 40,    40],
              [100, 100, 100],
              [50, 50,    50],
              [25, 25,    25],
              [10, 10,    10]]
    cords = [[-5.141, -114.9, 181.8],
             [-27.71, -99.95, 169.4],
             [51.29, -152.3, 213],
             [-16.43, -107.4, 175.6],
             [40, -144.8, 206.8],
             [68.21, -163.5, 222.3],
             [85.14, -174.7, 231.7]]
```

voxels list is corretly formatted but cords is not.
Couldn't find any vim tool that does this, any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: tbh, I'd argue that voxels could be formatted better as well, such as all of column 2 starts at the same line indentation.

Comment: See [Vim easy align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) or [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) for plugins that help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [Tabular plugin](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/tabular); once installed, go to the line starting with `cords =`, then run the following command (the end of the command may be different giving your own taste, see the plugin's help):

```
:.,.+6Tabularize /,/l0l1
```

This should give the following result:

```
cords = [[-5.141, -114.9, 181.8] ,
         [-27.71, -99.95, 169.4] ,
         [51.29 , -152.3, 213]   ,
         [-16.43, -107.4, 175.6] ,
         [40    , -144.8, 206.8] ,
         [68.21 , -163.5, 222.3] ,
         [85.14 , -174.7, 231.7]]
```